# What should we call our chat room

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2496/academia) has the default name of *academia*. Some sites have come up with [creative names](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=all&sort=active) for their chat rooms. It was suggested that we [rename our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31720109#31720109).

Should we rename our chat room and if so to what?

**UPDATE** the chat room has been renamed. We can change it again whenever we want, so keep proposing names and keep voting for the ones you like.

Comment: Suggestion on the procedure from experience: Should one wish to keep the current name, add another answer defending this option to be voted upon.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I propose ***[The Ivory Tower](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ivory%20tower)***, as this is the place where academics of all sorts clichéically and metaphorically live.

Answer (score 7):

As much of academia (profs, TAs) has them (or uses them in the case of undergrads), another option might be '*Office Hours*.'

Answer (score 6):

What about [**the common room**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Room_%28university%29)?

> Exist[s] to provide representation in the organisation of college or
>   residential hall life, to operate certain services within these
>   institutions [...], and to provide opportunities for socialising.

Seems to cover it to me. Every UK university I tried Googling used it (or a derivative such as JCR, MCR and/or SCR) in some form, most in the above sense ([Bristol, Cambridge, Durham, Exeter, Kent, Lancaster, Leicester, Nottingham, Oxford, Reading, St Andrews, Southampton, York](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Room_%28university%29#United_Kingdom), [UCL](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/ascr), [Birmingham](http://www.birmingham.ac.uk/maps/buildings/edgbaston-campus/red-zone/staff-house.aspx), [Hull](http://www2.hull.ac.uk/student/pdf/Accom%20Hull%202871.pdf)), some as the name of a physical social space ([Imperial](http://www.imperial.ac.uk/food-and-drink/catering-outlets/senior-common-room/)) or events facility ([Cardiff](http://www.cardiff.ac.uk/business/facilities/meeting-facilities/university-hall)). Some universities have named their online student communities or e-learning sites after it ([Manchester](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=manchester+university+virtual+common+room)).

It is also used in the US, although less common. Where used it seems to carry similar connotations, for instance the stated purpose of MIT's recently opened Quantum Information Science (QIS) Common Room is as a

> venue for impromptu technical discussions and [...] social
>   events

([link](http://www.rle.mit.edu/iquise/qis-common-room-grand-opening/)).

My only concern is that it might be biased towards the UK and other English-speaking countries.

Comment: Before visiting a university in the UK I thought that was a Harry Potter thing.

Comment: @Davidmh Yes, I've just edited to mention that one downside is that it might only really make sense to UK people. It is occasionally used in the US, Canada and Australia (if Wikipedia is to be trusted) but it's less common.

Answer (score 1):

If we're leaning a little more towards a research theme we could go with *The Lab*.

> I'm sorry I wasn't able to get your homeworks graded today, I was up late working in *the lab*.

Comment: If there isn't at least a spectrum analyser, it's not a lab :-p

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano The high-containment virus labs here would beg to differ :)

Answer (score 0):

I propose... ehm, cough cough... *The procrastinators' den*.

Comment: I think this title can apply to virtually any chat room on the Stack Exchange network, though :)

Comment: [productivity.se]’s chatroom is already called [Procrastination Station](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/598/procrastination-station).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ach, they beat me by far.

Comment: I'll vote for this when I get around to it; after writing my exam questions, doing the next set of powerpoints; completing the textbook draft, but first I'll just have this cup of coffee and read ....

Comment: @Wrzlprmft ...which hasn't had activity for the past 86 days.  They really need to learn how to procrastinate over there ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's go all Oxbridge and make it a **Senior Common Room**....

Comment: ...what's Oxbridge

Comment: Oxbridge is a shorthand for "Universities like Oxford or Cambridge" - c.f. Ivy League. Senior Common Room implies "no undergraduates" in such institutions, and thus matches the remit for Academia.SE

Comment: Ahhh I see - nice 

Answer (score 0):

To throw another suggestion into the den:

***The social event*** typically¹ refers to the excursion or similar at conferences, where attendees can talk about things other than the topic of the conference.

---

<sup>¹ at least in the my fields</sup>

Answer (score -1):

I propose [The Quad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrangle_(architecture)) as they are often a popular hangout on university campuses.

Comment: Reminds me of the discussion about our site design... just as with the campus clock tower, a Quad seems to me to be a very specifically US thing.

Comment: @StephanKolassa they are common in at least the US, UK, and Australia, but I am not sure about non English speaking universities.

Answer (score -2):

***Academia Secrets***, since people in the room seem to provide each other the scoop on things occurring at their respective institutions.